# function that highlight a word and extract the text near it

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

I have a text for example :

> Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Integer posuere erat a
>   ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Etiam porta sem
>   malesuada magna mollis euismod. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque
>   ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac
>   cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa
>   justo sit amet risus.
>
> Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vestibulum id ligula porta
>   felis euismod semper. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.
>   Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.
>   Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Integer posuere erat
>   a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.
>
> Cras mattis **consectetur purus**  sit amet fermentum. Etiam porta sem
>   malesuada magna mollis euismod. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel
>   scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
>   Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.

That text appears as description on a search performed in my website and i want  to be able to highlight a word/string and extract the text next to it.

Im not sure is the best way will be php(probably is) or just use a jquery function. I know how to highlight a word in jQuery but not sure how to extract the text.

In this example i want to show as description because my searched string is "consectetur purus" the following text.

> ....posuere velit aliquet.Cras mattis **consectetur purus** sit amet
>   fermentum. Etiam porta....

As you see im not only showing the highlighted word but also some text before and after it.
What would be the best method to accomplish this?

Im using the swish-e librari as search engine in my website and my knoledge of cgi is null so i prefer to try the php way.

Thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: str_replace($word,"<b>$word</b>",$result) ?

Comment: But that will still return the whole text , i just want to extract a summary of it. Maybe 10 words /100 characters before and after the matched word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a regular expression in php (you could do the same in JavaScript, though).

```
$regex = '/([A-Za-z0-9.,-]+\s*){0,5}\sconsectetur purus(\s|[,.!?])(\s*[A-Za-z0-9.,-]+){0,5}/';
preg_match($regex, $content, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

This matches 0-5 words built using alphanumeric chars or one of `.,-` (finetune this) followed by the words you're looking for (with or without punctuation at the end), followed by 0-5 words. This will never break up a word in the middle because a certain amount of chars is reached.

Output:

> posuere velit aliquet.
>
> Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Etiam porta

Now you can finetune this, e.g. remove the `\n`, add `...`, highlight `consectetur purus`…

Comment: Thanks a lot this did the trick. Let me ask you how i do if the word appear more than once in the text. Can i then extract all the pieces to show them togheter ?

Comment: @chifliiiii You might want to look at preg_match_all

Comment: @chifliiiii I improved the regex to allow punctuation at the end of your query :)

Comment: it seems that something broken in the last update as its not returning values any more . Just tried this same example in http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: Sorry i dont know why its not working on writecodeonline on my site wasnt working because i was writing my search like "consectur" but on the text is "Consectur". There is any way to match upper or lower?

Comment: @chifliiiii This should do the trick: `$regex = '/…/i';` (the `i` stands for case insensitive.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you get your answer after the searching request and the way the search engine works.

If you're target is "on typing" search, like "Google" has - then it'd be better to make it by php to cut the transferred data and waste less traffic.

Otherwise, if you get the whole text as a response and don't mind about the load - do it with JS using RegExp or counting `string.charAt( int )`.

Comment: Yep the text its already loaded as you thought. Can you give me some light on how to do it with javascript?

Comment: var x = x.replace( "([\S ]{,INT_CHARS_TO_LEFT})" + word + "([\S ]{,INT_CHARS_TO_RIGHT})" , "...$1<b>" + word + "</b>$2..." );

Comment: @chifliiiii Alternatively, look in the regex I posted in my answer.

Comment: @Michael: Comments on StackOverflow are meant to be just that: comments.  Even if you had used code formatting (which *is* supported in comments, though extremely limited), that code would have been too much for a comment.  When you want to expand your answer, simply edit it and add the new information.  And welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

We created a little library to do this. It will highlight the words you mention and give you an exerpt of the sentences around your query words.

```
$lorumIpsum = "three paragraps of lrum ipsum";
TextSnippet::createSnippet('Lorem', $lorumIpsum);
```

This will result in the following text:

**Lorem** ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ... Etiam bibendum **lorem** nec tempus sollicitudin. ... Sed in dapibus **lorem**. ... Nunc turpis ipsum, bibendum quis sodales sed, ullamcorper et **lorem**. Donec et metus hendrerit, interdum elit ut, dignissim dui.

The class als supports setting the html tag for highlighting with, and setting min- and max words fopr the snippet.

See [swisnl/textsnippet](https://github.com/swisnl/textsnippet) on Github.