# Regex to match a querystring in uppercase or lowercase

Tags: php, regex

In [this question @middus explained to me how to extract a word / string from a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897408/function-that-highlight-a-word-and-extract-the-text-near-it) so i can show the results highlighted.
I have the following function

```
$regex = '/([A-Za-z0-9.,-]+\s*){0,5}\sconsectetur purus(\s|[,.!?])(\s*[A-Za-z0-9.,-]+){0,5}/';
preg_match($regex, $content, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

`consectetur purus` is the query string that i inserted in my form. Problem is that in the text sometimes it appears like `Consectetur purus`.

How can i modify the regex pattern to match the query string i searched either is lowercase or uppercase and return the original text?

Comment: `/([A-Za-z0-9.,-]+\s*){0,5}\sconsectetur purus(\s|[,.!?])(\s*[A-Za-z0-9.,-]+){0,5}/i` will match case insensitive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use the /i regular expression [modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to allow for case insensitive searching.